# How to make a Flutter Podcast API call to display podcasts from one artist on itunes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc, flutter-bloc

here is this app https://github.com/amugofjava/anytime_podcast_player that displays podcasts from iTunes charts, in a discovery page. Is there a way to modify it to only display podcasts from only one artist on that page? for a college project.

Is there a way to change code to use an API call like "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253" somewhere in the code. I think it should be feasible, but I can't find it. Thank you so much for going through this.